# modal inside codeigniter loaded from view

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, modal-dialog

How can I load a page, namely a forgot password modal: `http://localhost/CI/index.php/forgot/forgotModal` into a div in my login page which displays the modal. For various reasons like it needing its only controller, I cannot include it in a view for `login`. At the end of my page I am calling:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {  
  App.init();
  $('#forgot-form').load('http://localhost/CI/index.php/forgot/forgotModal');
});
</script>
```

I am able to load the modal, but the submit button does not function.

Comment: Could you post the source of the view you're calling in forgotModal()? Or maybe even the HTML source of the resulting page (if you hit forgot/forgotModal directly from a browser)?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided enough information to solve the problem, but I will take an educated guess.. You probably have a JavaScript method which handles your form submission. This method is bound to a click event on a button displayed within your modal. The binding probably looks something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.submit').click(function() {
        handleForm();
    });
});
```

The problem is that the submit button was not part of the DOM when the page loaded and the binding was executed. What you want to do is use the .on() method and delegate to a node further up the DOM tree which **IS** part of the original page load. For example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').on('click', '.submit', function() {
        handleForm();
     });
});
```